# How can I keep a user logged in with SQLite?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have no problem making an account and logging in or registering. I want to make an option for users to update their gmail, password, or name. I also want the database to remember the user's name and gmail so all the user has to enter is their password. They should also be able to update their information.

How can I keep a user logged in? Here is what I have so far:

```
def createTabel():
    conn = sql.connect('user_data.db')
    print ("Opened database successfully")
    
    conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE user_info(
    
        name             TEXT     NOT NULL,
        gmail            TEXT     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        password         TEXT     NOT NULL,
        value            REAL         );''')
    print ("Table created successfully")

    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

To update existing information in the database, use:

cursor.exectue("UPDATE table SET columns = ? WHERE parameters = ?", parameters)

Where in the set part you put the fields to change and the parameters are the ones that are going to locate the column you want to change, you can also put it with f" " if you are more comfortable.

To insert data to the database it would be with:
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table(columns) VALUES(?)", parameters)

If you want to insert in all the columns, you should only put the table without the columns, leaving INSERT INTO table nothing else, depending on the number of columns, the number of ? and the data that is in the parameters is passed in the order of the columns

[image that make this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYqQb.png)

To know who is connected you must ask the name and with:

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE parameter = ?", (parameter))
values = cursor.fetchall()

That will create a list with all the values of the database